# How do I redirect the user if they get a certain string

Tags: javascript, html, css, string, random

I have some JavaScript code that prints a random string on the screen not random numbers and letters just words I created. So I need it so if it randomly chooses a certain string it redirects you to a different page.

Comment: Show us the code you're using.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if (randomString == 'patternString') {
   window.location.href = 'http://google.com';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
window.location.href = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=' + encodeURIComponent(randomString);
```